# How does AirPrint (on iOS) decide what printer settings to use, and can I change them?

Tags: ios, printing, airprint

I just got my first proper AirPrint printer (the Canon PIXMA 7120).

Like all printers, it has a ton of different settings for print quality, etc, and when you print from OSX, you get a print dialogue that lets you select things like

- Quality
- Media type
- Paper source
- Etc.

But when printing from iOS native apps (I was using "Photos") the only choice I got was to select the AirPrint printer to print to.

**When I printed, either iOS or the printer *seems to have decided to* use the tray that's dedicated to (4x6 or 5x7) photos, and to print in (high) photo quality, and spat out a beautiful print.**

It seems possible that it makes assumptions based on the app you start from ("Photos" is probably sending a picture, while "Pages" more likely has a doc.

So, my questions is:

**How does it decide what settings to use, and can I change them?**

I might want it to print an 8X10 photo, or a pages doc on photo paper, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The app ("Photos" in this case) makes those decisions based on your content and on what your printer supports.

If you are uncomfortable with this I have developed an app for printing photos that lets you control paper size, job type, sizes (inches or cm), crop, layout and ppi: http://www.clafou.com/print